# how to get payment status from payments made by a user via upi links (upi deep linking) shared to the user

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, web-deployment-project, upi, payment-method

I'm developing a web application that uses deep linking to create a UPI payment link that is sent to a consumer via email and SMS, the customer is able to make the payment by clicking the link. Is there a method for me to obtain the transaction ID and status of the payment that the customer made via the shared link?

Iam a novice in web development.I was therefore wondering if someone might assist me.  Iam using react for front end, nest js for backend and psql for database

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.